# How does pg_restore detect missing depending entities?

Tags: postgresql, backup, restore, pg-restore

A database `origin` was dumped in postgres *"custom"* format using: `pg_dump -d origin --data-only -Fc > file.dump`.

The dump was then used to restore all data in a **different database with the same table names**, as in the `origin` db. Command: `pg_restore -d target --verbose -Fc file.dump`.

```
;
; Archive created at 2024-03-19 14:00:10 UTC
;     dbname: origin
;     TOC Entries: 215
;     Compression: 0
;     Dump Version: 1.13-0
;     Format: CUSTOM
;     Integer: 4 bytes
;     Offset: 8 bytes
;     Dumped from database version: 11.18 (Ubuntu 11.18-1.pgdg18.04+1)
;     Dumped by pg_dump version: 11.18 (Ubuntu 11.18-1.pgdg18.04+1)
;
;
; Selected TOC Entries:
;
5357; 0 0 ENCODING - ENCODING
5358; 0 0 STDSTRINGS - STDSTRINGS
5359; 0 0 SEARCHPATH - SEARCHPATH
5360; 1262 16387 DATABASE - origin userA
5361; 0 0 DATABASE PROPERTIES - origin userA
;       depends on: 5360
5145; 0 730750 TABLE DATA subpartitions backends_y2024w03 userA
;       depends on: 237
5166; 0 738268 TABLE DATA subpartitions backends_y2024w04 userA
;       depends on: 258
5189; 0 745798 TABLE DATA subpartitions backends_y2024w05 userA
;       depends on: 281
.........
```

- **Problem:** Nothing was restored. As shown it seems like the *"custom"* backup dump has some `depends on: xxx` remarks encoded inside, which do not exist in the target database. Converting the dump to a plain SQL file, only containing commands like `COPY subpartitions.backends_y2024w03 ("time", dbname, data, tag_data) FROM stdin;`, imported all data **without any issues**.

**Question:** How are `depends on: xxx` missing entities detected, to what does `xxx` refer to when restoring a *"custom"* backup file and how to disable those checks? (as all real dependencies existed in the example)